# Gradle exclude multiple tasks programmatically

Tags: android, gradle

I am currently working on excluding specific tasks from the build process while executing the `.\gradlew build` command. I have been able to successfully exclude tasks via the excludeTaskNames. However I would like to exclude multiple tasks in a single line instead of adding each task per line?

```
gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames << "test"
gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames << "lint"
```

Answer (score 12):

If it is a gradle task you're trying to skip, consider using the `-x` command

```
./gradlew build -x test -x lint
```

Comment: Not command line based execution, need to add it into build.gradle directly

Comment: you can conbine arrays in groovy by using `+`, so you should be able to just do `gradle.startParameters.excludedTaskNames += ["test", "lint"]`. However, it's actually best practice to split up those to multiple lines because it's easier to read and less likely to trigger a merge conflict in source control.

Comment: should be  gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames += ["test", "lint"]